# finding all possible time combinations between a given time range

Tags: java, sorting, collections

I need to find unique digits present within all possible combinations of time (hh:mm:ss) between 2 specific times for ex 12:09:47 to 14:20:55. I'm currently I am doing the following:

1. Getting the seconds value from the start time
2. Adding 1 to this second's value and then generating the new
   LocalTime using the new value of seconds.
3. Comparing this new time to ensure its less than the end time.
4. getting the digits from hh:mm:ss and add them to a Set collection so only
   unique numbers are present by `(Set<Integer> uniqueDigits = new TreeSet<Integer>();)`

But then after adding 59 seconds, how do I increment the minutes and hours as well to go until the end of the time range?

I have the following code so far:

```
public int timeCombinations (String startTime, String endTime) {


        LocalTime end = LocalTime.parse(endTime);
        int count = 0;
        for (LocalTime t = LocalTime.parse(startTime, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss")); t.isBefore(end); t=t.plusSeconds(1)) {
//          System.out.println(t);
//          String timeStr = t.toString();
//          int second = t.get(ChronoField.SECOND_OF_MINUTE);
            System.out.println(t);
            Set<Integer> uniqueDigits = new TreeSet<Integer>();
            String hour = String.valueOf(t.getHour());
            String mins = String.valueOf(t.getMinute());
            String secs = String.valueOf(t.getSecond());

            uniqueDigits.add(Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(t.getHour()).substring(0,1)));
            if(hour.length()==2) {
                uniqueDigits.add(Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(t.getHour()).substring(1)));
            }

            uniqueDigits.add(Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(t.getMinute()).substring(0,1)));
            if(hour.length()==2) {
                uniqueDigits.add(Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(t.getMinute()).substring(1)));
            }

            uniqueDigits.add(Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(t.getSecond()).substring(0,1)));            
            if(secs.length()==2) {
                uniqueDigits.add(Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(t.getSecond()).substring(0,1)));
            }
```

I'm sure there is a better way of achieving the same result. Could anybody suggest an alternate way please?

Thanks

Comment: If you want to compare times, you should be using a built-in Java API (such as [LocalTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html)) instead of a String. Much of the work is already done for you

Comment: How about getting the timestamp of the start and end time and keep looping until your start timestamp reaches the end timestamp formatting the current timestamp to your favorite string format

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing something, but why not do:

```
static void timeCombinations(String startTime, String endTime) 
{
  DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss");
  LocalTime end = LocalTime.parse(endTime);
  for(LocalTime t=LocalTime.parse(startTime); t.isBefore(end); t=t.plusSeconds(1))
  {
    System.out.println(dtf.format(t));
  }
  System.out.println(end);
}
```

Test:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
  timeCombinations("12:09:59", "12:10:01");
}
```

Output:

```
12:09:59
12:10:00
12:10:01
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It works fine but for start time of 12:12:00, I'm unable to present the seconds as 00. Is there a way that I can represent the seconds in 2 digits for seconds values between 0-9?

Comment: Yes, you can use a `DateTimeFormatter`. I've edited the answer to show its use. It now produces `12:12:00` rather than `12:12`

Comment: I have already tried it but it didnt work, have uploaded the new code in my question

Comment: Any suggestions please why this is not working on my end?

Comment: What isn't working? The code in your question still looks too complicated. Can you use the code in my answer - or am I missing some detail of what it is you're trying to do?

Comment: Worked like a charm, appreciate for the amended code using DateTimeFormatter with format rather that when using it with parse()

Answer (score 2):

You can do with `LocalTime`.

```
LocalTime startLocalTime = LocalTime.parse(startTime);
LocalTime endLocalTime = LocalTime.parse(endTime);

while(startLocalTime.isBefore(endLocalTime)){
    startLocalTime = startLocalTime.plusSeconds(1);
    System.out.println(startLocalTime);
}
```

This will print all possible of between two date. 
To more info [Read Time Api](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html)

Just an option to get count of possible time of between two times with Duration.;

```
//duration calculates start and end date intervals.
Duration between = Duration.between(startLocalTime, endLocalTime);
//you can count how many seconds  or minutes or hours. 
//in your problem , getSeconds - 2 is your result between two time's possible
System.out.println(between.getSeconds());
```

In your code , count of possible dates calculating. Use like this and minus 2. Because start and end date should be removed in this calculation.

To more info read [Duration,Period Usage](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/period.html)

Answer (score 2):

Let's start by looking at the approach you're taking, the *String* approach. This is definitely doable. The code for it is below.

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
    String time1 = "12:09:47";
    String time2 = "14:20:55";
    List<String> times = getAllTimeValues(time1, time2);
}

public static ArrayList<String> getAllTimeValues(String time1, String time2) {
    ArrayList<String> times = new ArrayList<String>();
    times.add(time1);

    while (!time1.equals(time2)) 
        times.add(time1 = addOneSecond(time1));

    return times;
}

public static String addOneSecond(String time) {
    String[] HoursMinutesSeconds = time.split(":");
    int hours = Integer.parseInt(HoursMinutesSeconds[0]);
    int minutes = Integer.parseInt(HoursMinutesSeconds[1]);
    int seconds = Integer.parseInt(HoursMinutesSeconds[2]);
    if (seconds == 59) {
        if (minutes == 59) {
            hours++;
            minutes = 0;
            seconds = 0;
        } else {
            minutes++;
            seconds = 0;
        }
    } else {
        seconds++;
    }
    return String.format("%02d", hours) + ":" + 
        String.format("%02d", minutes) + ":" + 
        String.format("%02d", seconds);

}
```

Not too bad, this approach gets the job done in a pretty short amount of code. The bulk of the work is done with the addOneSecond method, which will check if the seconds are 60, then if the minutes are 60.

However, there is an easier approach. In Java 8, they changed Dates and Times, and they are very easy to work with. Let's take a look at another way to do exactly what the above code does.

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
    LocalTime time1 = LocalTime.of(12, 9, 47);
    LocalTime time2 = LocalTime.of(14, 20, 55);
    List<String> times = new ArrayList<String>();

    while (time1.isBefore(time2)) {
        times.add(time1.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME).toString());
        time1 = time1.plusSeconds(1);
    }
}
```

That is significantly less code than the first example! Again, with Java 8, you can work with these static members of the Date and Time classes. It makes it a lot easier to check all the times.

Comment: Adding extra point for the detailed explanation of the comparison between using the String and DateTime.

Comment: Also, I was struggling to get the time displayed in HH:mm:ss using DateTimeFormatter when it was 12:34:00 as it was being displayed as 12:34 and LocalTime .getSecond() on 12:34:01 was only returning 1 instead of 01. Your above suggestion of using format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME) worked perfectly fine!